# how to secure queries in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

The question is about duplicating queries in server/client in meteor.js.

here is a solution : https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/query-constructors/. There , the author proposes a shared file between client and server to hold the queries.

I have readed the article and I find it interesting but I have a question. If you put your queries in a shared file, the client also has access and can modify them? The security problem is not solved?

Comment: share your code snippet

Answer (score 1):

Code on the client is by definition *untrusted*. Conversely, code on the server is *trusted*. Code that is used on both the client and the server (often by being placed under `/lib` but also by being imported into both) is *untrusted* when running from the *client* and *trusted* when running from the *server*. Remember that the client gets a *copy* of the code, the users don't actually have access to the original on disk or the other copy that is in server memory.

With Meteor's *latency compensation*, a shared method runs on the client first. The client state (in minimongo) immediately reflects the state achieved by running the method. Then the method runs *again* on the server. If the result is different in some way, then the client state is updated from the server with the correct data.

If you want to hide the method's logic from the server you can just not include it in your client code. You will forego latency compensation but you will keep your secrets secret! (ex: API keys, critical business logic). You can also have pure server code, such as startup scripts and cron jobs, that are never even invoked from the client.

Comment: ok but how to hide queries in client then. i need queries in server and client side .

Comment: You can't *hide* the queries on the client. They will get minified and obfuscated by Meteor's build process but the user can still see them and reverse engineer what you are doing on the client.

Answer (score 0):

In Meteor, **nothing** on the client can **ever** be trusted or considered safe. There is simply no way you can "hide" stuff on the client. If the browser can run it, a hacker can read it. And modify it.

Remember that queries on the client run on data on the client, and then the result of those queries is sent over a web-socket to/from the server. It is then **the job of the server** to do security/authorization/sanity checks on all data going out or coming in, to make sure only the data the client is authorized to view is sent, and only the modifications the client is allowed to do is actually done on the server DB.

The Discovermeteor blog you linked to is all about how to reduce code duplication between server and client, and still have flexibility between them. This has very little to do with security.

It does not really matter from a security point of view that the source code for the DB queries are readable on the client, because your server needs to do its security police job anyway. Otherwise you have an insecure app, even if the actual query source code is unknown.

An attacker can always look at the DDP protocol, it is almost as readable as a MongoDB query!

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is inaccurate. The client-side query will run client-side only. Nothing gets transmitted to the server. If it was a shared method call, the method will get re-run on the server side. If the result of the query is the same (i.e., the same data is returned), then nothing else happens, since the client and server agree. OTOH, if the data is different, then the server pushes the updated data to the client. This is what Meteor calls latency compensation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking 2 different questions:

1) How do you ensure the *security* of a query?

2) How do you ensure the *secrecy* of a query?

WRT #1: Keeping a query in a shared lib file is secure because regardless of whether a client knows what query you're running, he won't be able to run it on the server and even if he changes it, that only alters the client copy, and doesn't affect the server's copy.

In the example you link to, note that the client is *only* able to change the limit field. He can't change the 'find' field. Even if he were to redefine the 'latestPost' function client-side to allow an additional parameter that gets added to the 'find' field, that function isn't redefined on the server-side so only the original definition will be used server-side (one point, however, is that in the example, the limit field isn't sanitized or checked for validity; a client could send text and cause an error).

So it would still be secure as you are limiting exactly which parts of the query constructor the client is allowed to change.

WRT #2: you're correct that this means the query won't be *secret*. The client will know exactly how you're querying, and with that info, may be able to deduce parts of your internal data structure.

Whether or not this is an issue is up to you, although I will say that in the security world, "security through obscurity" is considered bad practice: you should write your code such that *even if* all of your data structures, algorithms, and code is known, your data is still secure. That's why, for example, you can easily download the code for any encryption algorithm: the security doesn't depend on keeping the algorithm secret.